# A problem concerning continous function spaces and divergence of series

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, orthogonality

Saw this on a website, having no clue.

> Let $C([0,1])$ be the space of real continous functions on the interval $[0,1].$ Let $\{a_n\}$ be a series such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{a_n}$ diverges, $a_0=0,$ and $a_n\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty.$ Show that, if $\int_0^1x^{a_n}f(x)dx=0$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N},$ then $f\equiv 0.$

I know that the proposition to be proved is equivalent to the completeness of the system $\{x^{a_n}\}$ in $C([0,1])$ with the integral(convolution) inner product. I can't see the relation between the series' divergence and the system's completeness.

An example is that when $a_n=n,$ the series is well-defined and divergent, and we get the desired result by the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. But there is still no clue when $a_n$ is a general series. I can't even construct an example when $a_n$ converges and a non-vanishing function that satisfies the orthogonal condition.

Any thoughts, solutions, and other clues are welcome.

Comment: My idea is to approximate polynomials by $x^{a_n}$ but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Look up the Müntz–Szász theorem.